# Killing a Java Process started from a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, process, interrupt

I have developed a JSP web application which, on every request, spawns a new Java Thread. In every newly spawned thread I create a Process using Runtime.exec() and store the process object in an instance variable in thread. I have a requirement in which I have to kill the created subprocess and also stop the thread. So, I overrode the interrupt method in the thread and in the overridden method I'm calling destroy() on already stored Process object in the instance variable. Following is the code:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    private Process subprocess;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        subprocess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("myprocess.exe");
        subprocess.waitFor();
        /*
            Some more statements
        */
    }

    @Override
    public void interrupt() {
        if(subprocess!=null) {
            System.out.println("Destroying Process");
            subprocess.destroy();
        }
        super.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Is it illeagal to override interrupt method? 
Its important that I kill the created process before I interrupt the thread that creates it. I see that the thread does get interrupted because the statements after waitFor() **do not get executed**. But, however, destroy() **doesnt work** (but gets called) and the created "myprocess.exe" completes execution even if I call interrupt() method before its completion. Can someone please help me out with this? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not illegal to override `interrupt`, but I wouldn't recommend it. Perhaps a cleaner way to do this would be:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    private Process subprocess;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        subprocess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("myprocess.exe");
        try {
            subprocess.waitFor();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            subprocess.destroy();
        }
        /*
            Some more statements
        */
    }
}
```

Don't forget that you should also pull data from the subprocess output/error streams, otherwise you might wind up with full buffers and a blocked subprocess. It's OK to read from those streams and discard the data. I suspect the `commons-io` package has tools to make this a one-liner, otherwise it's a fairly simple method to write yourself.

Comment: but isnt InterruptedException thrown only if interrupt() method is called when thread is under blocking-wait state? Is it also thrown when the thread is under busy-waiting? Like in a for or while loop?

Comment: If you are busy-waiting, then you need to test `Thread.interrupted()` yourself. But why would you busy-wait? Spawn off a couple of daemon threads that each just read an `InputStream` to EOF, then die. One for `subprocess.getInputStream()` and one for `subprocess.getErrorStream()`.

Comment: The InterruptedException gets caught but still, in the catch block, calling destroy() doesnt kill the subprocess. However when I do not pull the messages from the Input and Error Streams, The subprocess doesnt even start. Any idea why?

Comment: It might be that the subprocess is the problem, or maybe Windows or the JVM doesn't implement process termination well (I'm assuming you're on Windows since you had a .exe in your code). Try starting a different, simple process and see what happens.